# Proof directed to maximum and minimum orders of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have to proof the following statement: If the minimum order of a graph $G$ is $1$, the maximum is $k$ and the order of $G > 2k$ -> at least three vertices will have the same degree.

I have tried with examples and seen that if you draw a path of size $4$, for $k = 2$ you have $3$ vertices with the maximum degree in the middle and for $k \ge 3$ you can stack the maximum degree at the end of the same path and have $3$ vertices of degree $2$.

I don't know how to make this into a proof or if I'm in the wrong direction. Does anyone know how I could continue,make this a proof or go in another direction? Thanks.

Comment: If $|G|>2k$ this follows immediately from the pigeonhole principle.